# How can I see indicator-sync in LXPanel?

Tags: indicator, lubuntu, lxpanel

I've installed indicator-sync (Universe) but he doesn't appear in the panel.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to indicate the source of "indicator-sync" and any other details that maybe relevant? I don't see "indicator-sync" as an option in the default list of applets in Lubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this might be a forum zombie - it might help someone.

Coming from a bug filed on launchpad by a user with the same name, I suppose the Ubuntu One Indicator Plugin applet from Roman Yepishev (https://launchpad.net/indicator-ubuntuone) is meant here.

bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-ubuntuone/+bug/1076056

Solution:

Simply copy the starter to the folder where Lubuntu can find it:

```
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-ubuntuone.desktop .config/autostart/
```

Note that this will work only after a new login. If you want it to work instantly, use the following command line:

```
/usr/lib/indicator-ubuntuone/indicator-ubuntuone &
```

Hope it helps